# Huawei Mobile broadband modem not being detected

Tags: networking, usb-modem, mobile-broadband, 3g

MODEM MODEL NUMBER : Huawei E3531 (E3531s- 1)
OS : Ubuntu 21.10

This modem model only supports up-to 3G (HSPA+) and works with Windows 10 but not with Ubuntu 21.10. `lsusb` output shows `Bus 002 Device 113: ID 12d1:1446 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. HSPA modem` with the list of other devices.

I'm confused what to do and this model of modem is pretty old too...

Edit : `sudo dmesg|grep USB` shows `[    4.059217] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic [    4.068865] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for GSM modem (1-port) [    4.070247] usb 2-3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0 [    4.071005] usb 2-3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1 [    4.073750] usb 2-3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2`

Comment: `usb_modeswitch` should work out-of-the-box for that modem. Then is just a matter of setting up the proper ISP.

Comment: I'm not seeing any option to setup the modem in setting or when I plug it in as explained in the question.

Comment: (Assuming standard Ubuntu with Gnome) When you click in the top right corner, in the middle section of the dropdown menu, you should see a mobile connection wizard. If not you may need to manually issue an `usb_modeswitch` command. Just google your model (or even the VID:PID) + Ubuntu and you'll find some old discussions about it.

Comment: I'm using GNOME and not seeing mobile broadband option. `usb_modeswitch` shows many ways to use the command but can you tell me how to properly do it as I'm a noob (sorry). Also, I googled ubuntu +model number couldn't find anything relevant or missed something (I'll try again)

Comment: @ChanganAuto made edit, might help me solve the issue, please take a look

Comment: According to the dmesg result and as expected, no need to switch.

Comment: Yes, it should just work as a modem with the correct settings for the ISP. The only reason for the `usb_modeswitch` like the name suggests it for those cases (of many years ago) when the modem connects as a "CD-ROM" or mass storage - enables mounting a small drive with Windows drivers (XP and early 7 version) - so using that command was needed in Linux to switch to the actual modem mode, something that happened automatically in Windows after installing the drivers. Linux always had the drivers but unless the modem was recognized as such it wouldn't work. Yours is in the correct mode already.

Comment: Now, you do have a working SIM card inserted, don't you? Does it have a PIN enabled? Try using it in a normal phone and disable the PIN request just to make thing easier. Again, it should be as simple as selecting the wizard to choose country, ISP and plan (if applicable).

Comment: I have working SIM card not sure about any PIN but I found this https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-mobile.html.en which say to make sure 3G modem is not set as an USB mass storage device. I will check with another sim card and post a comment

Comment: I connected a working Vi SIM card with no PIN but no result!

Comment: @ChanganAuto I opened advanced network configuration app on Ubuntu and add new device which is mobile broadband but can't select the device, what to do?

Comment: @ChanganAuto Okay I also noticed about 10-11 second Modem is shown as USB mass storage

Comment: @ChanganAuto I tried it with proper working SIM card but still no I went to setting (mobile broadband setting) says no device found